# How to get Zone Name (Asia/Karachi) using Country Name?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I search for about 2 and 3 hours but not find which I ask.
Example: If I pass the countryName: India and its return Zone name Asia/Kolkata.
Pakistan its return the Zone name Asia/Karachi

```
public String getCode(String countryName) {
        String[] countriesCode = Locale.getISOCountries();
        for (int i=0;i<countriesCode.length;i++) {
            locale = new Locale("", countriesCode[i]);
            if (countryName.equalsIgnoreCase(locale.getDisplayCountry())) {
                TimeZone timeZone=TimeZone.getTimeZone(countriesCode[i]);
                return timeZone.getID();// I wants to return here like Asia/Karachi
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: What about countries with multiple zones?

Comment: in the case of multiple zones, I select the zone on the capital base. but if you know  answer what I am asking please answer it and thank you for your response

Comment: You mean you want the timezone ID with the name of the capital city of that country? You do realise that does not always exist, right? For example, for China, there is no `Asia/Beijing`, but there are many timezones in China, including `Asia/Urumqi`, `Asia/Chongqing`, `Asia/Hong_Kong`, `Asia/Shanghai`.

Comment: Ok,  Is there any solution to set time in an analog clock of selected country?

Comment: No, just a country is not enough information. You at least need a city, or even something smaller than that.

Comment: If I have the country code and country name like PK for Pakistan or IN for India is it enough information? if enough then please correct me I have stuck from 2 to 3 hours.

Comment: Pakistan and India currently uses one timezone across the whole country, so it is unambiguous. But in general, this is not true, because some countries have multiple timezones. Australia has 7, for example.